# How to edit setup SFDX_APEX_LOG_COLOR_MAP in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Following a blog post about debug logs on [this](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/03/14/streaming-apex-logs-to-your-console/) page, we're able to customise the colour the command `sfdx force:apex:log:tail` outputs by using the `SFDX_APEX_LOG_COLOR_MAP` environment variables.

Like this:

```
    {
        CONSTRUCTOR_: 'magenta',
        EXCEPTION_: 'red',
        FATAL_: 'red',
        METHOD_: 'blue',
        SOQL_: 'yellow',
        USER_: 'green',
}
```

Can someone explain where and how I can add this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set this you will need to create a JSON file with contents you have posted in question and then note the full path of this JSON file.

Then you can set the path of the JSON file using environment variable `SFDX_APEX_LOG_COLOR_MAP`

Depending on your operating system you can set environment variable following instructions shown below.

For **macOS** set the below

```
 export SFDX_APEX_LOG_COLOR_MAP=<path of your json file where you have color map>
```

For windows set the environment variables as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0)